# var o const en API REST en node.js

Tags: nodejs

Mi pregunta es que es mejor practica usar **var** o **const** para cargar módulos en una **api node.js**

por ejemplo:

```
var http = require("http");
```

o

```
const http = require("http");
```

veo sitios que usan **const** y otros **var** pero alguien me cual es la diferencia y porqué es mejor usar uno que otro?

Comment: No, esta entrada ya la vi pero no responde la pregunta.

Comment: En qué no la responde?

Comment: Si explica muy bien en cada caso cuando usar cada tipo de variable en javascript pero mi pregunta va mas alla y es cual es mejor práctica en Node.JS si declarar con const o var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia es que al declarar una const debe iniciaizarse inmediatamente y el valor no se puede cambiar después.`const http` a diferencia de `var http`que puedes cambiar el valor en cualquier momento y no necesariamente tienes que inicializarlo.